# Why does printing from this struct give a segmentation fault?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create an array of Product structs and then print the name and code of each Product in the array, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. I have tried to insert each value without a loop and then printing, and it works, but I'd like to automate it. The function fill_products fills the products array according to the user's input, and the select_products prints each name-code pair for the entire array.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int code;
    char *name;
    float price;
} Product;

void select_products(Product *products, int len)
{
    int i;

    printf("%-30s%s\n", "Name", "Code");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%-30s%d\n", products[i].name, products[i].code);
    }

    return;
}

void fill_products(Product *products, int len)
{
    int i, code;
    char *name;
    float price;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert product name (%d / %d): ", i + 1, len);
        scanf("%s", &name);
        printf("Insert product price (%d / %d): ", i + 1, len);
        scanf("%f", &price);

        products[i].code = i;
        products[i].name = name;
        products[i].price = price;
    }

    return;
}

int is_alloc(Product *products)
{
    if (products == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: memory allocation unsuccessful.\n");
    }
    return products != NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int len, n_bytes;
    Product *products;

    printf("Insert length of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &len);

    n_bytes = sizeof *products * len;
    products = malloc(n_bytes);

    if(!is_alloc(products))
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    fill_products(products, len);
    select_products(products, len);

    free(products);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I keep getting a segmentation fault.

Please enable compiler warnings, and *pay attention* to them.

This code:

```
    char *name;
...
        scanf("%s", &name);
```

is bogus and doesn't do *at all* what you intend.

You must either *allocate* space for `name` separately (and then not forget to `free()` it), or make that space available in the `Product` structure like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    int code;
    char name[100];
    float price;
} Product;
```

(this assumes there is a reasonable limit on `name` length).